# how to pass data through @selector upon custom button click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, selector

I'm making a button via code.
I have the following line of code to trigger a method when the button is clicked:

```
[imagesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(photoClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown ];
```

The problem is that I can't pass data to the method through the @selector;
If the button had a background image name "background.png" how would I go about sending the name of the background image to the method when the button is clicked?
This all HAS to be through code.

Thanks!

-Shredder

Answer (score 2):

there must be a way to comment on an answer, but I don't know what it is. Anyway, Gobot above me forgot to write (id) before sender in the method declaration. Otherwise Gobot's example is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're trying to change a property of the button whose sending the message, your selector should have a parameter of `sender`, which is a pointer to the object that called it, which is your button in this case. For example:

```
- (void)photoClicked:(id)sender {
    UIImage bg = [sender currentBackgroundImage]
}
```